# Does a proof of $0 + 0 = 0$ and $1 + (-1) = 0$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

The axiom of the additive neutral establishes that for every real number there is another that fulfills that when it is added the number does not change.

But the axiom does not say that for every real number the sum of that number with zero is the number.

The second I can prove from the first if I find a proof of $0 + 0 = 0$

Can someone help me?

My axioms are

$0 \in \mathbb{R}$

$1 \in \mathbb{R}$

For every $A$ and $B$  in $\mathbb{R}$

$A + B = B + A$

A + (B + C) = (A + B) + C

AB = BA

A(BC) = (AB)C

A(B + C) = AB + AC

For every A exists B such that

A + B = A

For every A exist B such thar

A + B = 0

For every A different from 0 exist B such that

AB=A

AB=1

Comment: Can you precisely state the axioms that you're using?

Comment: In your system, what is $0$?  Is it defined to be the additive identity element?  Something else?   And how is $-1$ defined?  Is it the additive inverse of $1$?  Something else?

Comment: Since you added "real analysis", I assume the system of axioms that you're using are that of first-order fields?

Comment: Echoing @lulu's comment: usually the $0$ element is defined/characterized/postulated/axiomatized to satisfy $0+a=a$...

Comment: I have established my axioms Mark Saving

Comment: lulu, in my sistem 0 is the name of the number zero

Comment: Where did you find those axioms?  Generally speaking the additive identity is defined *for all* real numbers, not just for each particular real number.  That is, one says that $A+0=A$ for all $A$.  Not that there is some $B$, which might be specific to $A$, such that $A+B=A$

Comment: The only axiom of yours that mentions zero ($0$) is the one that says for every $A$ there exists $B$ such that $A+B=0$.  But this isn't enough to characterize zero.  In fact for every real number $C$ it is also true:  for every $A$ there exists $B$ such that $A+B=C$.  So your axioms might not be as complete as you want.

Comment: $0$ is *usually* DEFINED to be a number with the property that $A+0 = A$ for all $A$ (and that such a number exists is assumed by axiom).  So *by definition* If $A= 0$ we will have $0 + 0 = 0$ by definition.  And $-A$ is defined to be a number with the property that $A+(-A) = 0$ (and that all numbers have this negative inverse is axiomatically presumed).  So *again* by definition.... $1 + (-1) = 0$.

Comment: Also you refer to $0,1$ without ever defining what $0$ and $1$ *are*.

Comment: Can you cite what *book* you are using?

Comment: "lulu, in my sistem 0 is the name of the number zero "  But what *is* the number zero?  What does it mean?

Comment: your system is very badly incomplete. You _need_ to add the axioms "for every $a$, $a+0=1a=a$."

Comment: I still suspect the OP has misread their axioms since they don't specify 1 at all, but to all the people saying this is impossible, I'm not convinced there isn't a positive answer under these axioms. It might be possible to leverage the fact that 0 appears in the last two axioms, together with the distributive law, to prove the exact result the OP has asked for.

Comment: These axioms specify 0 as the unique number with no multiplicative inverse, and the question doesn't care whether 1 is actually the multiplicative unit or not (it would be more helpful if it wasn't labelled as 1 in the axiom system).

Comment: @1Rock, the axioms do not say that 0 does not have a multiplicative inverse. They do say that all other numbers do. But they do not even say that $0\ne 1$. I do not see anything above that prevents $\mathbb{R}$ from being equal to $\{0\}$.

Comment: In that case, 0+0=0.

Comment: Yes, but in that case, the set is not the real numbers. So I guess the question I would have for the OP is, "Do you just want to know if those two statements can be proven in your theory, even if your set is not necessarily the real numbers (in which case you're confusing the matter by calling your set the real numbers), OR do you want to know if your axioms define the real numbers?"

Comment: The latest edit has  $\forall A\ne 0, \,A=1$

Comment: Are the last three lines supposed to be ... such that $AB=A$ AND $AB=1$, or two separate axioms?

Comment: Not everything has to be proven. We have axioms for groups, rings and fields. No need to invent the wheel over and over again.

Answer (score 5):

The field axioms include:

- There is an additive identity.
- There is a multiplicative identity.
- Every $x$ has an additive inverse.
- Every $x\neq0$ has a multiplicative inverse.

Now, suppose that the numbers $e_1$ and $e_2$ are both additive identities. Then, $e_1=e_1+e_2$, as $e_2$ is an additive identity; but $e_1+e_2=e_2$, as $e_1$ is an additive identity. Hence, $e_1=e_2$. This shows that the identity element is unique, meaning that we can speak of *the* additive identity. From here, it is just a matter of convention that we use the symbol "$0$" to denote the additive identity of a field. And then it follows trivially that $0+0=0$.

Now, it is common to define the real numbers axiomatically as a field satisfying certain properties, namely that it is ordered, and that it satisfies some version of completeness (e.g. the least upper bound property). Your list of axioms aren't enough. You have asserted that $0\in\mathbf R$ and that for every $A$ there is a $B$ such that $A+B=0$. However, these properties are true for *every* real number. You need to define $0$ by a property that marks it out as unique. And this property is typically that it is the additive identity.

Almost exactly the same remarks apply to the multiplicative identity, and additive inverses and multiplicative inverses: after showing that these are unique, we denote them by $1$, $-x$, and $x^{-1}$ (or $1/x$).